# How does osmnx know which edges to plot in shortest path

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

According to the documentation an edge is uniquely defined by three parameters: `u`, `v` and `k`. SO even though u and v can be the same the parameter `k` differentiates between the edges

When I calculate the shortest path between two nodes I use `nx.shortest_path`. This gives me a list of the nodes that are in the shortest path.

Let's take an example, let's consider nodes 1 and 2. Now I calculate the shortest path between them and the result is the following:

```
[1, 4, 6, 7, 2]
```

If there is an egde `u=4, v=6, k=0` and another `u=4, v=6, k=1` how can I know which one is the one in the shortest path? How does osmnx know since it can plot the given shortest path?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of OSMnx. It sounds like you're asking about its `plot_graph_route` function. In the case of parallel edges (i.e., multiple edges between some node `u` and some node `v`) along the shortest path, OSMnx picks the edge that is shorter in length. You can see exactly how it handles this [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/d7e8eb4121ddc5b1afc861df4dd24a2d58e9ff74/osmnx/plot.py#L302-L303).

Comment: I could not see a statement that deals with edges of the same length. I suppose it does not matter which is selected if the lengths are the same?

Comment: Correct. It will be up to the arbitrariness of which gets returned by the min function, if the values are equal.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have two questions in it. I can answer the part involving `networkx`.

### `Graph`:

To be a little pedantic (and because I'm imagining future people Googling this), this *does* depend on the type of graph you're working in. We'll start with a generic graph:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
G.add_edge(2, 8, weight=0.3)   # A
G.add_edge(2, 8, weight=0.6)   # B
G.add_edge(1, 8, weight=1.0)

for u, v, w in G.edges(data=True):
    print(u, v, k)
```

... and consider what happens if we switch the order of the lines marked `A` and `B`:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
G.add_edge(2, 8, weight=0.6)   # B
G.add_edge(2, 8, weight=0.3)   # A
G.add_edge(1, 8, weight=1.0)

for u, v, w in G.edges(data=True):
    print(u, v, k)
```

In both cases: the network will look the same:

[image: Path graph showing six nodes connected by six edges]

But the parameters of our network are different in the two cases:

```
# A first
0 1 {}
1 2 {}
1 8 {'weight': 1.0}
2 3 {}
2 8 {'weight': 0.6}
3 4 {}
```

and

```
# B first
0 1 {}
1 2 {}
1 8 {'weight': 1.0}
2 3 {}
2 8 {'weight': 0.3}
3 4 {}
```

So here: the answer is that `u`, `v`, and `k` are unique and the list returned by `shortest_path` will be unique.

### `MultiDiGraph`:

I'm 90% sure this is the case the question wants to ask about. In a `MultiDiGraph` the nodes are still indexed by `u`, `v`, but there can be multiple weights `k`:

```py
import networkx as nx

GM = nx.MultiDiGraph()
GM.add_edge(0, 2, weight=0.3)
GM.add_edge(0, 2, weight=0.15)
GM.add_edge(1, 2, weight=0.1)
GM.add_edge(0, 1, weight=0.1)
GM.add_edge(2, 3, weight=0.4)
GM.add_edge(2, 3, weight=0.5)

for u, v, w in GM.edges(data=True):
    print(u, v, w)

path = nx.shortest_path(GM, source=0, target=3, weight='weight')
print(path)
# [0, 2, 3]
```

The list returned by `nx.shortest_path` is ambiguous, but it's pretty straightforward to reconstruct the path of least weight:

```py
for u, v in zip(path[0:], path[1:]):
    edge_data = GM.get_edge_data(u, v)
    min_weight = min([edge_data[edge]['weight'] for edge in edge_data])
    print(f"{u}---({min_weight})---{v}")
```

Result:

```
0---(0.15)---2
2---(0.4)---3
```