# networkx MultiDiGraph access keys of edges making the shortest path

Tags: python, networkx

Using the [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/) library, I define a *MultDiGraph*. I then calculate the shortest path between two given nodes. As my graph holds parallel edges, I would like to know the **keys** of the edges that make up the shortest path. Here's an example:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge('a', 'b', key=0, weight=1)
G.add_edge('a', 'b', key=1, weight=2)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', key=0, weight=1)

shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, source='a', target='c')
shortest_path_length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source='a', target='c')
    
print(shortest_path)
print(shortest_path_length)
```

The result looks like this:

> ['a', 'b', 'c']
> 2

This is only correct if the shortest path between nodes 'a' and 'b' is via the *key=0* (weight=1). I couldn't find anything in the docs that would allow me to retrieve the keys of the actual edges involved in the shortest path. How could I get to this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you cannot. `Networkx` does not have a functionality that returns the edges that comprise the shortest path. At most it can return the nodes that are in that shortest path.

A work around this is to assume that the edges in the shortest path are the shortest ones, therefore if two nodes in the path can form an edge with a key of either 1 or 0, assume it is the shortest one.

I have faced the same issue as you in: [How does osmnx know which edges to plot in shortest path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141647/how-does-osmnx-know-which-edges-to-plot-in-shortest-path)

I used a library called OSMNx and the feature I wanted needed to know which edges make the shortest path. The feature makes the same assumption as I have stated above (you can see the answer to the question)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand your assumption and on first thought it makes sense, too. I wonder if one can find an example where this assumption does not hold true. Anyhow, for now I go with it and will mark the answer as correct if no one comes around with a proper way of retrieving the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, source='a', target='c', weight='weigth')
node_edges = []
for p in nx.utils.pairwise(shortest_path):
    step1 = (G.get_edge_data(*p).items())
    step2 = min([d.get('weight') for k, d in step1])
    node_edges.extend( (k, d) for k, d in step1 if d.get('weight') == step2)
print(note_edges)
```

The output is the edge data:

> [(0, {'weight': 0}), (0, {'weight': 1})]

Firstly, `nx.utils.pairwise(shortest_path)` gets you tuples of node pairs from the list of nodes in the shortest_path, which you can use to get edge data.
In step1 get all possible edges between the nodes.
In step2 find the min weight. In your example the sorting key for weight is easy, a simple min() would do, but a custom sorting based on a different edge attribute is also possible.
Lastly, find the edge where the edge attribute matches step2 and add it to the list of `node_edges`.
If anyone has a quicker, simpler idea, please let me know.